Case of omission of subject relative pronoun "that"
In the video  linked here (at 12m30s), the subject pronoun "that" is omitted (the sentence follows).

… his freefall was flawless, and he twirled beautifully in the sky like a bird knows its way home. (One expects "like a bird that knows its way home")

In CoGEL, omission of this pronoun or zero pronoun as it is called in that book, is mentioned only for the objective case. In CGEL no mention is made either of this possibility as part of standard  or colloquial English.

(CGEL p 1055) That cannot normally be omitted if the relativised element is subject of the relative clause

Further explanations from CGEL show that the instance found in the video would be non-standard.

(CGEL p 1055)
non-subject i a. The car [that I took ] was Ed’s.
ii a. The car [I took was Ed’s.
subject ib. The car [that hit us] was Ed’s.
iib. ∗The car [hit us] was Ed’s.


(CGEL p 1055) The prohibition on dropping the that with relativised subjects is associated with the need to distinguish the subordinate relative clause from the matrix predicate. Since hit us in [ib] immediately follows the car, there is nothing to stop the listener construing hit us as the main clause predicate, with the car as its subject: that prevents such a misconstrual by explicitly signalling the start of a subordinate clause. This is not to suggest that there would always be a danger of misconstrual if that were omitted from clauses with a relativised subject. In ∗We didn’t take the number of the car hit us, for example, the car is complement of of and hence not a possible subject for a predicate hit us. The grammatical restriction preventing subject relativisation with bare relatives covers a wider range of cases, but the point is that it includes those where that serves a role in aiding perception of the structure.
Some varieties of English do allow that to be omitted from clauses with relativised
subjects under certain conditions:
[68]
i ?It was my father [did most of the talking]. [it-cleft]
ii ?There’s someone at the door [wants to talk to you]. [existential]
iii !Anyone wants this can have it.
Most such cases are clearly non-standard, like [iii]. The status of [i–ii], where the relative clause functions within an it-cleft and existential construction respectively, is less certain: they fall at the boundary between very informal and non-standard. Note that the position of the relative clause in [i–ii] is such that it could not be misconstrued as predicate of
the matrix clause.

The whole narration is in perfectly standard English; so, should it be concluded from that that this non-standard use of the zero-pronoun is  merely an odd occurrence in it, or rather that a recent trend has come into being? Where would this usage be  known as becoming acceptable?
The question asked more than ten years ago, What allows the omission of subject relative pronouns, is answered in the present question in the CGEL reference used to make the point (see above), and does not explore this  problem, which might be extant today, whereas it was not necessarily so ten years ago.
Note
CoGEL: A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language, Quirk et al
CGEL: The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, Huddleston & Pullum

We can't tell what was intended but my strong impression is that the object of like is not an NP headed by the noun bird, but rather a finite clause.

Is it just me, or does that simile not make any sense?

Either it's a mistake, or I'd think it meant '… he free-fell flawlessly and twirled beautifully in the sky, as naturally, as effortlessly, as a bird finds its way home.'

I don’t think this a zero-that situation. Birds do know their way home. I’m getting something like Just like a bird knows its way home, he [did too].

@TinfoilHat "To twirl like a bird knows sth" ("sth" having nothing to do with twirling) does not make any sense either.  Perhaps the author/authors has/have a particular kind of bird in mind, such as homing pigeons or migratory birds,  creatures showing the ability to brave  with much self-assurance an (apparently) greater difficulty than  that of merely returning to a local nest.

I agree it doesn’t make much sense, but I don’t think there’s a that missing; cf. His appetite was boundless, and he ate greedily like a pig eats slop [not a pig that eats slop].

It's quite possibly an allusion to a poem, which may use non-standard English (it sounds kinda Maya Angelou-ish). I wouldn't assume it represents a general change in the laws of English such that you must update all your writing, which seems to be what you're implying.

Perhaps knows takes on more meaning here. Instead of finds its way home, it knows its way home, physically, which requires all the navigating means they have available, some still unknown to scientists. Poetic license, jargon, colloquialism? IDK, just a guess.


he twirled beautifully in the sky like a bird knows his way home

The line in question, when read in the only way the grammar allows, is simply a comparison of manner between his twirling beautifully in the sky and a bird knowing his way home. What makes one second guess it is that it is such an awkward comparison.
The typical pattern is to repeat the same verb in both clauses:

Jack needed Baby Huey under his wing like a duck needs a concrete flak
jacket. (Let Sleeping Dogs Lie)

Though plenty of examples can be found where the verb is different.

You cultivate your body's bacteria like a farmer tends his fields.
His ears pricked up at the sound of high heels echoing across the
asphalt like a shark scents blood. (Run from fear; Alden, Jami; 2012
)

Unfortunately for the speaker of the lines in question, manners of twirling and knowing are not generally described similarly; it would be awkward to say that a bird beautifully knows his way home.
The more salient interpretation is that he twirled beautifully in the sky like a bird twirls in the sky, which they apparently would do beautifully when assured of a safe resting spot.
In the end, absent a slew of other examples of similar (which have proven difficult to find) we can chalk this up to an abortive attempt at simile. Everyone, even those with usually impeccable English, slips up sometimes, especially in speech or when reading a script as is likely here.

As the sentence is written, and from my point of view, it is either not grammatical or it is defective as to its meaning, and you seem to agree with that; but you say nothing about the possibility of adding the relative "that", which makes it grammatical and gives it at least some plausible meaning ("he twirled beautifully, as does a bird…" ). It would seem that you reject the eventuality of the author having felt (erroneously or otherwise) a zero-pronoun; am I right?

I agree also with your recognition of the necessity of a certain compatibility between the two verbs (a purely semantic question), which do not have to be the same.
